# Python Pandas - Finding a substring in dataframe then sum without loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Currently doing string equality

```
df['Contains string'] = (df[columns] == 'myString').sum(axis=1)
```

How can I do the same thing but finding a substring instead of a fullstring, something like

```
df['Contains string'] = (df[columns].contains('myString')).sum(axis=1)
```

But that doesn't work. Also tried `str.contains, series.index, series.find`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is not implemented for `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Contains string'] = (df[columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('myString'))).sum(axis=1)
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `sum` by first level, thank you @anky:

```
df['Contains string'] = df[columns].stack().str.contains('myString').sum(level=0)
```

Or if no missing values is possible use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `in`:

```
df['Contains string'] = (df[columns].applymap(lambda x: 'myString' in x)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: also i prefer : `df[columns].stack().str.contains('myString').sum(level=0)`